# What's the best way to Natty Narwhal 11.04 upgrade?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

format and install from zero or upgrade my current 10.10 Ubuntu installation?
if I upgrade my current Ubuntu, Is it possible that I will not have the same look and feel of a fresh installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want your data to be erased, the best option is to update it via the Update Manager. 
It will not be the same look since from version 11.04 Ubuntu ships with a new Desktop Interface 'Unity'. It will not look like the Gnome Desktop Environment, your current Ubuntu (10.10) have.

Comment: Rather calling it a "new Desktop Environment", consider using a "new Desktop Interface" or "Shell", calling it a different DE takes it away from GNOME, and it hurts. ;-)

Comment: yeah, i know it's unity and because of that, obviously, will not be the same look as gnome. but it's possible i loose performance on 10.10 or anything like this by upgrading from update manager?

Comment: No I don't think such an issue would occur. I'm using Upgrade Manager from version 9.04 to upgrade my Ubuntu installation and I haven't faced a single issue. Of course, it goes without saying that sometimes, a fresh distribution would cause some problems due to bugs. but they will be patched as the time passes and distribution gets matured over time.

Comment: I upgraded and the panels just disappeared in the Unity side but not in the gnome side. Wondering what happened.  The unity might just not be fully developed.

Comment: @Sam, Yes that's possible. It takes some time to a freshly released distribution to stabilize. Maybe a patch will be released soon to answer such issues. (I also read somewhere that some of pre-release testers managed to crash Unity in the testing phase.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on personal preference, so in my case I would opt for a clean installation.  Always remember to backup your data so the transition is made just that bit smoother.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Already upgraded and am having problems so I may wipe.